# Tkinter, design is messed up and i can't make it look good

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Im trying to make a simple gui for a tool that im using to send sms text messages, but the placement of entries and labels is not correct. It feels wonky and weird:

[image]

For some reason the text fields are just messed up and the input for the message text field is just a mess.
Could someone please help me out to make it look a bit cleaner?

What im trying to achieve is something like this:
[image]

Or something like this:
[image]

This is my code:

```py
from tkinter import *

def send_message():
    print('sent')

def clear_text():
    print('cleared')

#window object
app = Tk()
# Sender
Sender_text = StringVar()
Sender_label = Label(app, text='Sender', font=('bold', 14), pady=20)
Sender_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
Sender_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=Sender_text)
Sender_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
# Receiver
Receiver_text = StringVar()
Receiver_label = Label(app, text='Receiver', font=('bold', 14))
Receiver_label.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=W)
Receiver_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=Receiver_text)
Receiver_entry.grid(row=0, column=3)
# Message
Message_text = StringVar()
Message_label = Label(app, text='Message', font=('bold', 14))
Message_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
#Message_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=Message_text)
Message_entry = Text(app, width=20, height=2, font=("Bold",20))
Message_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
# Buttons
send_btn = Button(app, text='Send', width=12, command=send_message)
send_btn.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=20)
clear_btn = Button(app, text='Clear', width=12, command=clear_text)
clear_btn.grid(row=2, column=1)
```

Any help is highly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "messed up" and "just a mess"?

Comment: Maybe you could show what you would like the gui to look like instead?

Comment: Thats a good idea, ill draw it. Give me a second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Layout is at least partially a matter of taste.
But this is what I've come up with:

[image: tksms-modified]

I've put the entry window on its own line, and used `columnspan=4` to make it span all four columns.
Additionally, I've moved the buttons to the third and fourth column.

```
from tkinter import *

def send_message():
    print('sent')

def clear_text():
    print('cleared')

#window object
app = Tk()
# Sender
Sender_text = StringVar()
Sender_label = Label(app, text='Sender', font=('bold', 14), pady=20)
Sender_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E)
Sender_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=Sender_text)
Sender_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
# Receiver
Receiver_text = StringVar()
Receiver_label = Label(app, text='Receiver', font=('bold', 14))
Receiver_label.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=E)
Receiver_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=Receiver_text)
Receiver_entry.grid(row=0, column=3)
# Message
Message_text = StringVar()
Message_label = Label(app, text='Message', font=('bold', 14))
Message_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
Message_entry = Text(app, width=20, height=2, font=("Bold",20))
Message_entry.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=4, sticky=EW)
# Buttons
send_btn = Button(app, text='Send', width=12, command=send_message)
send_btn.grid(row=3, column=2, pady=20)
clear_btn = Button(app, text='Clear', width=12, command=clear_text)
clear_btn.grid(row=3, column=3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.attributes('-type', 'dialog')
    app.mainloop()
```

The "trick" is to make a sketch of how you want your GUI to look, and then draw the grid lines to fit:

[image: with grid]

Widgets may cover multiple rows and/or columns, but they must cover *whole* cells.

Comment: Thank you so much, its perfect. Its basically a homemade app so i just needed a clean layout. Mine hurt my ocd..

Comment: Practice makes perfect. :-) BTW, I've added what I think is the "trick" about using the `grid` layout manager.

Comment: Could i ask something related to this. I use Message_entry to take input from user and then get that input using message = Message_text.get() but it doesnt seem to work because its a Text and not an Entry. Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: @Nora The `Text` widget also has a `get` method. See [here](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/text.html). I don't think you can use `StringVar` with a `Text` window.

Comment: This example doesn't handle being resized very well at all.

Comment: @BryanOakley True, but the OP didn't ask about that. Lately I've been trying to just answer the question instead of trying to shoehorn a whole intro-to-tk course into my answers. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I prefer using pack and frames, it tends to work better in resizable windows, or when you need to adjust things later, since it's less rigid on item placement.

Here's an example:

[image]

```
from tkinter import *

def send_message():
    print('sent')

def clear_text():
    print('cleared')

#window object
app = Tk()
# Sender
SR_frame = Frame(app)
Sender_text = StringVar()
Sender_label = Label(SR_frame, text='Sender: ', font=('bold', 14))
Sender_label.pack(side = 'left')
Sender_entry = Entry(SR_frame, textvariable=Sender_text)
Sender_entry.pack(side = 'left', padx = (0, 20))
# Receiver
Receiver_text = StringVar()
Receiver_label = Label(SR_frame, text='Receiver: ', font=('bold', 14))
Receiver_label.pack(side = 'left')
Receiver_entry = Entry(SR_frame, textvariable=Receiver_text)
Receiver_entry.pack(side = 'left')
SR_frame.pack(padx = 20)
# Message
#Message_text = StringVar()
Message_label = Label(app, text='Message', font=('bold', 14))
Message_label.pack(pady = 20)
#Message_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=Message_text)
Message_entry = Text(app, width=20, height=2, font=("Bold",20))
Message_entry.pack()
# Buttons
btn_frame = Frame(app)
send_btn = Button(btn_frame, text='Send', width=12, command=send_message)
send_btn.pack(side = 'left')
clear_btn = Button(btn_frame, text='Clear', width=12, command=clear_text)
clear_btn.pack(side = 'right')
btn_frame.pack(pady = 20)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, could i ask something related to this. I use Message_entry to take input from user and then get that input using message = Message_text.get() but it doesnt seem to work because its a Text and not an Entry. Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: @Nora You want to use `Message_entry.get(1.0,'end')` to get the contents of the textbox.

Comment: Thank you so much, its flawless.

Comment: sorry to bother, i have one last question. I have a button that clears the fields but it doesnt seem to work on the Message one because its a text and not an Entry. previously i used "Message_entry.delete(0, 'end')" to clear it but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: @Nora Have you tried `Message_entry.delete(1.0, 'end')`? `1.0` means "line 1, character 0", line 0 doesn't exist.

Comment: This version of code doesn't handle resizing very well. If I make the window taller, the message window doesn't grow and the buttons end up in the middle. If I make the window narrower, the right-most entry widget gets chopped off pretty quickly.

Comment: @BryanOakley No, it would need the proper fill and expand properties set, I was simply making a comment that it can handle that situation more easily.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to solve all of your layout problems at once. Divide your UI in to logical sections, and work on each section separately.

You clearly have three sections in your dialog:

- a top section with two inputs and two labels,
- a middle section with a label and text area, and
- a bottom section with a button

Further, it seems likely that it is the middle section that you want to take up all extra space, while the other widgets should retain their size and position.

#### Creating the basic structure

To do that, start by creating three frames, and laying them out. `pack` is really great for this since pack puts widget along an entire side of an empty space. For this example I'm going to use PEP8 guidelines for the imports and variable names, and I've fixed the buggy font specifications.

```
import tkinter as tk

def send_message():
    print('sent')

def clear_text():
    print('cleared')

root = tk.Tk()

label_font = ("Helvetica",14, "bold")
text_font = ("Helvetica", 20, "bold")

top = tk.Frame(root)
middle = tk.Frame(root, padx=8, pady=8)
bottom = tk.Frame(root, padx=8, pady=8)

top.pack(side="top", fill="x", padx=8, pady=8)
bottom.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
middle.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
```

#### The top labels and entries

Now we can focus on the top part. This one looks like a little one-row grid, so `grid` makes the most sense here. Since you aren't using any special features of `StringVar`, there's really no need to use them here.

```
label_font = ('bold', 14)
sender_label = tk.Label(top, text="Sender", font=label_font)
sender_entry = tk.Entry(top)
receiver_label = tk.Label(top, text="Receiver", font=label_font)
receiver_entry = tk.Entry(top)

# let the columns with entry widgets grow and shrink
top.grid_rowconfigure((1,3), weight=1)
sender_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="e")
sender_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ew")
receiver_label.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="e")
receiver_entry.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky="ew")
```

#### The middle section

The middle section has a label and a text widget. Since they are arranged top-to-bottom, `pack` works nicely. We want the text widget to take up all available space so we use the `fill` and `expand` options.

```
message_label = tk.Label(middle, text="Message", font=label_font)
message_text = tk.Text(middle, width=20, height=2, font=text_font)

message_label.pack(side="top", fill="x")
message_text.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
```

#### The bottom section

And finally, the bottom portion with the buttons. It has two buttons that are centered. `grid` is useful for this, too. Have one button hug the right side of the first column, and the other button hub the left side. This isn't the only way to do it, but it's a good illustration of how to use both `pack` and `grid` in an application (just not in the same frame).

```
send_btn = tk.Button(bottom, text='Send', width=12, command=send_message)
clear_btn = tk.Button(bottom, text="Clear", width=12, command=cleared)

bottom.grid_columnconfigure((0,1), weight=1)
send_btn.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="e")
clear_btn.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="w")
```

#### Finishing up

Call `mainloop`, and we are done. To get the values out of the entry widgets you can use `sender_entry.get()` and `receiver_entry.get()`. I renamed `message_entry` to `message_text` to limit confusion; to get all of the data out of it you can use `message_text.get("1.0", "end-1c").

Notice that when you resize the window, everything resizes appropriately. I took this screenshot on a mac where it's default colors are white rather than gray, but otherwise it matches one of the examples in your question.

[image: landscape screenshot]

[image: portrait screenshot]

#### Summary

Don't treat layout as an afterthought. Plan ahead, and use frames to organize your UI in logical sections. You can then work on each section independently of the others. If you try to cram everything into the root window and try to organize it all with `grid` you'll have to readjust everything each time you want to add, remove, or move widgets.

In addition, don't intersperse layout code with widget creation code. Create all of the widgets that share the same master together. Likewise, group all of the calls to `pack`, `place`, or `grid` together for widgets that share the same master. It makes the code much easier to visualize and understand. Instead of a big wall of code, you can now clearly see which widgets are related, and how they are organized relative to each other

Answer (score 1):

Using the `.place` method serves to be the most useful.

The `.place()` method helps you to precisely calculate your GUI widgets position.

The `.grid()`and `.pack()` are a bit messy as they are controlled by the widget's parameters, whereas the `.place()` method can help you achieve precise placement.

You just need to make good calculations with the root window real estate

Here is an example with `.grid()` placement:
[image]

You can actually see that there is a small difference between the button with 7 and the button with (-) symbol. this is because there is a difference between sizes of Unicode characters and normal characters.

Here is an example with `.place()` placement:
[image]

You can see that the problem with the last example is solved with the `.place()` method.
This is because , this method uses the relative occurence.

Hope this helps!!

btw.. This is the calculator that I am currently working on.

Comment: Hello, I think this answer would be great if you include some relevant code (example use of `place()`, or even better if you can provide the code and screenshots of `place()` applied to the specific question.